# Pejorative word for events like ribbon-cutting ceremony, Association party & fests which are counterproductive activities for an organization

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, idioms, pejorative-language

Pejorative word for attending "ribbon cutting ceremonies, ribbon cutting ceremonies, Association parties and fests" by a country's missions post abroad who are meant to be engaged in welfare of country's diaspora in a foreign country but instead do the above activities.

Example: The Ecuadorian embassy in Poland is hopeless and indifferent, they are most involved in ___________ (ribbon cutting ceremonies, Association parties and fests)

Answer (score 4):

**Dog and pony show**

This is explained in Wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_and_pony_show

> ...a colloquial term which has come to mean a highly promoted, often
>   over-staged performance, presentation, or event designed to sway or
>   convince opinion for political, or less often, commercial ends.
>   Typically, the term is used in a pejorative sense to connote disdain,
>   jocular lack of appreciation, or distrust of the message being
>   presented or the efforts undertaken to present it.

So for your example,

*The Ecuadorian embassy in Poland is hopeless and indifferent, they are mostly involved in **dog and pony shows**.*

Answer (score 1):

[***pomp***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/pomp) (Ceremony and splendid display, especially at a public event.) ***and pageantry***; ***razzmatazz***

> **ceremony**, ceremoniousness, ceremonial, solemnity, ritual, **display**, **spectacle**, pageantry, pageant
>
> **show**, showiness, **ostentation**, splendour, grandeur, grandness, magnificence, majesty, stateliness, glory, gloriousness, sumptuousness, opulence, lavishness, richness, brilliance, radiance, dazzle, theatricality, **drama**, flourish, glitter, style, éclat, resplendence, splendidness
>
> *informal* pizzazz, razzle-dazzle, **razzmatazz**

src: ODOL

Emphasis of select entries mine, to suggest as possible options.

Comment: I like the 'pageantry' - it captures both the splendour of such official occasions, the vacuousness and the parade-like circumstances.

Comment: Most of these synonyms are not answering the OP's question.  A pejorative term was specifically requested.

Comment: @JDM-GBG Most of these are used pretty pejoratively and have a scathing effect on the target when delivered with a tone of sarcasm.

Comment: @Kris, yes, anything is a pejorative when said sarcastically.  But more than half of these can be used just as readily in a sincere and laudatory way.  And the OP also specifically requested a word specific to a public ceremony; these are much more general in their usage.

Comment: BTW I agree with @loonquawl, "pageantry" is absolutely on the mark.  IMO the answer would be perfect if you cut out all the other options and stuck to that one.

Comment: @loonquawl *Pomp and pageantry* is a common enough idiomatic phrase, though some may argue that it is an incorrect form of "pomp and ceremony."

Comment: @JDM-GBG Oh, thanks for reminding me. I forgot to add **1** the block quote;   **2** that I have bolded those entries I suggest as possible options.  Hang on!

Comment: Edited. That should do.

Comment: Yes, perfectly clear now.

Answer (score 0):

*The Ecuadorian embassy in Poland is hopeless and indifferent, they are most involved in **window dressing**.*

> **window dressing**
> noun [ U ] (DECEIVING)
>
> DISAPPROVING things that are of no real importance and are said or done in order to make an attractive effect:
>
> *How many of the candidate's policies are real intentions, and how many are just window dressing?*
> — https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/window-dressing

Comment: This would be a better fit if the embassy was putting out flashy but content-less press-briefs or somesuch